# SQL - Perform Partial match of string value using a table of options

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named **FileList** that has one column with a list of file names (that have no standard naming convention) that is similar to the following:

```
FileName
--------------------
\Brady_John\Direct Deposit and Voided Check.pdf
\Brady_John\Handbook Acknowledgement Form.pdf
\Brady_John\W-4, 2017.pdf
\Brady_John\Direct Deposit Change.pdf
\Brady_John\EE Handbook Certificate-May 2019.pdf
\Smith_Mary\Direct, Direct Deposit_chase.pdf
\Smith_Mary\2015 W4.pdf
\Smith_Mary\Illinois State Witholding Form.pdf
```

I am attempting to normalize and extract relevant data from these names. For example, if the text "w-4", "w4" or "w" appears in the filename, it is *probably* a "W-4 Form". A rudimentary and limited example of doing this is:

```
SELECT FileName
    ,CASE 
        WHEN FileName LIKE '%W-4%'
            OR FileName LIKE '%W4%'
            OR FileName LIKE '%Witholding%'
            THEN 'Form W-4'
        ELSE NULL
        END AS DocType1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN FileName LIKE '%Deposit%'
            THEN 'Direct Deposit Form'
        ELSE NULL
        END AS DocType2
    ,CASE 
        WHEN FileName LIKE '%Handbook%'
            THEN 'Handbook Acknowledgement'
        ELSE NULL
        END AS DocType3
FROM FileList
```

However, using CASE statements creates separate columns (I only want one column named DocType) and is not very manageable if I want to deal with a couple of hundred matching cases. I am trying to find a way to use a secondary matching table to provide the options to find the proper document type like the following:

```
MatchedWord    DocType
-------------- ------------------------
W-4            Form W-4
W4             Form W-4
Witholding     Form W-4
Deposit        Direct Deposit Form
Handbook       Handbook Acknowledgement
```

I realize that if I can figure this out that I'll need to deal with matching precedence order, but for now, all I care about is trying to create and use this matching table.  Note that stored procedures and cursors are not preferred, but will be accepted if there is no other option.

Comment: dont use multiple CASE.  just use 1 with multiple WHENs.  you are very close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maintain a mapping table.

Notice the `IsNull(...,'Undefined')`  this will raise any issues

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([FileName] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('\Brady_John\Direct Deposit and Voided Check.pdf')
,('\Brady_John\Handbook Acknowledgement Form.pdf')
,('\Brady_John\W-4, 2017.pdf')
,('\Brady_John\Direct Deposit Change.pdf')
,('\Brady_John\EE Handbook Certificate-May 2019.pdf')
,('\Smith_Mary\Direct, Direct Deposit_chase.pdf')
,('\Smith_Mary\2015 W4.pdf')
,('\Smith_Mary\Illinois State Witholding Form.pdf')

Declare @Mapping  table (KeyPhrase  varchar(50),MapTo varchar(50))
Insert Into @Mapping values
 ('W-4','Form W-4')
,('W4' ,'Form W-4')
,('Witholding' ,'Direct Dep Form') 
,('Handbook' ,'Handbook Ackknowlegement') 
,('Deposit' ,'Direct Deposit Form') 

Select A.*
      ,DoctType = IsNull(B.MapTo,'Undefined')
 From @YourTable A
 Left Join @Mapping   B on charindex(KeyPhrase,FileName)>0
```

**Returns**

```
FileName                                            DoctType
\Brady_John\Direct Deposit and Voided Check.pdf     Direct Deposit Form
\Brady_John\Handbook Acknowledgement Form.pdf       Handbook Ackknowlegement
\Brady_John\W-4, 2017.pdf                           Form W-4
\Brady_John\Direct Deposit Change.pdf               Direct Deposit Form
\Brady_John\EE Handbook Certificate-May 2019.pdf    Handbook Ackknowlegement
\Smith_Mary\Direct, Direct Deposit_chase.pdf        Direct Deposit Form
\Smith_Mary\2015 W4.pdf                             Form W-4
\Smith_Mary\Illinois State Witholding Form.pdf      Direct Dep Form
```

Comment: That's perfect!  I didn't know how to use the line stating " Left Join @Mapping   B on charindex(KeyPhrase,FileName)>0", but that was the "special sauce".  Thanks!

Comment: @bigmac Happy to help.  Notice I fixed  a couple of typos in the mapping table

Answer (score 0):

A case expression can multiple conditions. You just need to combine them instead of making each type a separate column. Something like this.

```
SELECT FileName
    ,CASE 
        WHEN FileName LIKE '%W-4%'
            OR FileName LIKE '%W4%'
            OR FileName LIKE '%Witholding%'
            THEN 'Form W-4'
        WHEN FileName LIKE '%Deposit%'
            THEN 'Direct Deposit Form'
        WHEN FileName LIKE '%Handbook%'
            THEN 'Handbook Acknowledgement'
        ELSE NULL
        END AS DocType
FROM FileList
```

**--EDIT--**

Since you are wanting to have the conditions in a table just create a table with two columns. One for the value you want to find and a second for the value you want returned. Then simply join to that table. Since this should be a one time thing you just use wildcards in your join.

Comment: Thanks Sean, and that makes sense.  However, it doesn't solve the root problem which is wanting to manage and maintain a couple of hundred matching conditions in a separate matching table as opposed to hard coded within the T-SQL statement.  Any thoughts on that?